# FastAPI column products.category_id does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, migration, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI and I am stuck in this error while adding columns to a Model class

Here are my models

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    description = Column(String)

    products = relationship("Product", back_populates="category")


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    title = Column(String, unique=True)
    price = Column(Float)
    cost = Column(Float)

    category = relationship("Category", back_populates="products")
```

when the API is running I got this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column products.category_id does not exist`

And the problem go on, if I try to add a new attribute to Porduct model there are no changes in my database columns

There is something like run migrations in FastAPI? What I am missing?

Comment: Well, direct deleting the table and reloading the API works for me, but should be a better way to add new attributes to a model.

Comment: same, i've to delete the table then run the app again so it can reload and re-create a new table to apply the update.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use something like Alembic to manage DB migrations. FastAPI does not manage this for you. Here's an example project from FastAPI that shows how to set up Alembic migrations.

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#alembic-note

https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/alembic/